# Blackberry's Status Four Way input?

Tags: blackberry

The documentation for Field in the BB 4.7 API @ 
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#navigationClick(int,%20int) shows that the source of a navigationClick can be determined "by checking the KeypadListener.STATUS_TRACKWHEEL and KeypadListener.STATUS_FOUR_WAY bits in the status parameter" and that "exactly one of them will be set".

I'm having trouble understanding some of this documentation. Would anyone be able to explain what the "four way input device" is that STATUS_FOUR_WAY represents? And if the navigationClick event is triggered by a touch-screen pointer press event (eg: on the Blackberry Storm), which of these bits should I expect to be set? It doesn't seem like either one of these is the "correct" source, but the docs imply one of them will be set.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If  you are programming for a Storm you should use the version 5.0 of the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "four way input device" is the trackwheel on older device than Storm, like the Curve and the Bold.

When you move it, you can catch which "way" the user is using the wheel.

Has for the Screen touch, the best way to know what it triggers is reading the API 5.0, or testing it yourself.

In the 5.0 API they recommand using this `Screen.navigationClick(int, int)`

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html